# Monitor the traffic of the local network, each computer

Tags: c#, networking, traffic

You need to monitor the traffic on the local network, each computer. It might not be a bad man-in-the-midl system. But maybe there is an example sharppcap library that could be useful.

Comment: Use wireshark or fiddler to capture the traffic.  You can use macro in the application.  They are built using Sharppcap.

Comment: can i write this on c# ?

Comment: See following : https://github.com/chmorgan/sharppcap/commit/c8aff4891fa1af0db1be487b7eab925f18f0ee42